# Is using both client side certificate and JWT for IoT device redundant?

Tags: tls, certificates, jwt, iot

Is there a case to be made for authorizing with both a client side certificate and JWT for an IoT device?

Are JWTs good enough (assuming following of the specs)?

And if client side certs are truly needed, what of expiration dates? (set the client cert expiration way out into the future, etc)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you left out the (obvious?) case of *only* using certificates?

Comment: @TomK. Excellent question. Yes, we already use JWTs everywhere. Client side certs would be new for us. Also, JWT seems more resilient over time (new ones are generated as needed vs. with a set expiry date etc)

Comment: You might want to revisit your assumption that JWT is a useful general security measure: https://nemethgergely.com/building-secure-javascript-applications/, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdJ0wFi1Jyo, https://speakerdeck.com/rdegges/almost-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-web-authentication-in-node

Comment: @JulianKnight - Those references make sense for javascript type apps (browsers and SPAs), but I don't see the parallel for an IoT device authenticating to an API

Comment: It depends on the security requirements and the sensitivity of the data. JWT is only really secure for short lived tokens. The best use of JWT is for a single use token. If you want long-lived authentication, sessions are a much more appropriate and secure method - according to those references.

Comment: How are you issuing the JWTs? How do the devices authenticate to the server? Do the devices have long-lived refresh tokens or similar persistent credentials (other than TLS client certs) on them? In general, JWTs are only useful for a short timespan, so you can't do something like provision a device with one before it ships; you need to have the device authenticate (which means it needs credentials) and then it gets a JWT and refresh token. How are you doing the authentication? And are the JWTs even adding anything beyond the client TLS cert?

Answer (score 0):

Only reason you need the additional JWT is if there are going to be different claims and identities being used with the devices that require seperate privileges.

Now as this is IoT do you have a way to revocate and update certificates? Are you able to handle all the required certificate operations?

Comment: So, your answer makes it sound like a client cert is enough for security (as long as more claims aren't needed), but what about the reverse? What about JWT without any client side cert (still over tls)?